# Correct way to add AWGN to a signal

Tags: matlab, noise, gaussian, snr, bandwidth

I have a signal, S whose bandwidth is `bw` Hertz and is sampled at `fs` Hertz.

To contaminate it with a noise corresponding to SNR `x` dB, I used the matlab function

`out = awgn(S,x);`

But I have came across some codes doing it instead like the following.

`out = awgn(S,corrected_x);`

Where `corrected_x = x + 10*log(bw/fs);`

Which is the correct method and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short answer

`10*log(bw/fs)` to take into account the oversampling operation because the `awgn()` function specifies the signal-to-noise ratio **per sample**, in dB.

### Longer answer

The discrete time AWGN model is

$$Y = X+N$$

where X is data from continuous time $X(t)$, N is noise sequence from AWGN process $N(t)$ and Y is receive symbols.

If $X(t)$ is characterized by its baseband equivalent limited between $[-W/2, +W/2] \textrm{ (Hz)}$,  then we can identify $X(t)$ by observing $Y$ at a rate $W$ symbols per second. [See chapter 2, sampling theorem and Theorem of irrelevance](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-451-principles-of-digital-communication-ii-spring-2005/readings-and-lecture-notes/MIT6_451S05_FullLecNotes.pdf).

Call $P$ the average power (joules per second). The sample power $E_s= P/W$ and the noise symbol power is $N_0$. The signal noise ratio **per symbol** is defined $\mathrm{SNR} = \frac{P}{BW_0} = E_s/N_0$.

If the complex baseband signal is oversampled $\alpha = f_s/W$, the noise sample power is still $N_0$ while the data sample power is reduced $\alpha$ times, thus $E_s/N_0 = \mathrm{SNR} \times W/f_s$.

In dB, $E_s/N_0 = \mathrm{SNR} + 10\log_{10}{(W/f_s)}$.

The `awgn()` function add AWG noise by the previously defined $E_s/N_0$.

Comment: here SNR = Es/N0, so when over sampling is there, Es is reduced by factor of alpha, which would make SNR = (Es/alpha)/N0 right??
then isnt it Es/N0 = SNR * Fs/W ?

Comment: By definition, SNR = Es_no_oversampled/N0. With oversampling, awgn() function paramater snr is Es_oversampled/N0 = (Es_no_oversampled/alpha)/N0 = SNR/alpha = SNR*W/Fs

Comment: Why is noise still N0 is it because the noise has infinite bandwidth so the images overlap? What if it's bandlimited won't it scale with the symbol

Comment: @LewisKelsey because the continous AWGN process is only observed via instruments and, therefore, the noise power is independent of bandwidth. Actually I did ask the same question and got [a thorough answer from MBaz](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/38968/26081)

Comment: @LewisKelsey check also [this lecture note](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/Newlectures/Lecture03.pdf)

Comment: So... the sampled symbol's images in the freq domain already have a power scaled by the sampling rate, in the discrete theoretical dirac delta time domain model, which gets normalised when you reconstruct the symbol from the samples. So Es/N0 refers to the discrete signal energy (height of each of the infinite images in power spectrum) to N0, and SNR is Es/oversampling factor / (N0/2), and apparently when you reconstruct a signal containing awgn, noise apparently remains N0/2 but signal image decreases by multiplication by reconstruction filter. What u sent was partially helpful but I'm lost

Comment: 'The data sample power decreases by alpha'. I think this is wrong. When you double the sample rate, the signal power doubles. Matlab site says that Es/N0 is SNR * alpha https://uk.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/awgn-channel.html#a1071501088. I think SNR is the comparison between the signal power (now double) and noise in the sample bandwidth (now double) and Es/N0 is comparison between the now double symbol power, and the noise within the symbol bandwidth, which is the same, so Es/N0 is double SNR

Comment: @LewisKelsey do not forget that oversampling does improve SNR, but only with low pass filter by combining uncorrelated noise samples and therefore reducing *filtered* noise power. The SNR is improved because of the decrease of noise power, not because of an increase of signal power.

Comment: @LewisKelsey also, my $\textrm{SNR}$ is actually the $E_s/N_0$ of MATLAB (see my definition) and my last equation is the input of function `awgn()` which is what MATLAB called $\textrm{SNR}$.

Comment: @AlexTP yes im not confusing this with the quantisation noise PSD of sampling being reduced by oversampling and i dont know why that happens either. How can Es/N0 have a different definition to another Es/N0. I dont even know what Es/N0 is anymore

Comment: @LewisKelsey because the awgn() function cannot distinguish sample and symbol. I defined the terms that way to explain why the function uses SNR as the input. You can use your own terminology, but the principle does not change.

Comment: @AlexTP I initially thought that Es/N0 was double SNR when you double the sample rate because SNR halved when you double the sample rate because Pn  becomes larger as the bandwidth of noise in the sampling bandwidth doubles, but N0 is the same. I initially thought it was this simple but  Is this an incorrect measure of SNR?

Comment: @LewisKelsey this is correct if by SNR you mean the ratio (the power of oversampled signal sample)/(the power of noise sample).